# background transition fix and background dim on hover [fiddle inside]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got completely stuck on this. I have a container with background image. Inside the container are 3 little circles. What I am trying to do is to zoom the background image when I hover over it and dim the background image when I hover over any of the 3 little circles.

I got to the point where the 3 circles are properly overlapping the container and the background zooms in on hover. But I have 2 issues

**no. 1 I am not very fond of the way I am achieving the overlay of the circles, which is this code**

```
    #circle_wrap{
    position: absolute; 
    margin-top: -130px;
    }
```

**no. 2 Is that I have no clue how to dim the background. My original intention was to have a hidden black conteniner with 0.5 opacity that would be displayed when I hover over one of the circles. But I couldn't figure out how to select the overlay.**

[JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/n3r8yta4/2/)

If anything couldn't be solved with css only, I'd accept jquery solution as well.

I'm looking for any advice/tips/solutions you guys have, I really need to get this working.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got so angry I am not able to do it with css that I made it with jquery :(
If anyone is interested [here is the result](http://jsfiddle.net/n3r8yta4/20/)
I have at least fixed the issue no1 with better css but the second is done with jquery.

solved no.1 with

```
.circle_wrap{
position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 100px;
}
```

and applying `position:relative` on its parent

and the solution for no.2 is

```
$(".circle_wrap").hover(function () {
  $(this).siblings("img").css("opacity", "0.2");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).siblings("img").css("opacity", "1");
});
```

**EDIT:** safari support

```
.wrap img:hover{
-moz-transition: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg);
transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg);
-webkit-animation-name: scaleThis;
-webkit-animation-duration:5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes scaleThis {
0% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
10% { -webkit-transform:scale(1.1) rotate(0deg); }
100% {-webkit-transform:scale(1.1) rotate(0deg); }
}
```